# Conversion from Function to sets of custom types

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, typeclass

I have a set of classes that looks something like this, which are (annoyingly) not in a single inheritance hierarchy:

```
trait Mxy[A,B] { def apply(a: A): B }
trait Mzz[ C ] { def apply(c: C): C }
trait Mix[  B] { def apply(i: Int): B }
trait Mxi[A  ] { def apply(a: A): Int }
trait Mii      { def apply(i: Int): Int }
```

The challenge is to map `Function1` into these classes using converters (so you call `.m` to switch over); direct implicit conversion makes it too hard to figure out what the code is really doing.

As long as the most specific `M` is always okay, it's doable.  You can write implicit conversions that look something like

```
abstract class MxyMaker[A, B] { def m: Mxy[A, B] }
abstract class MiiMaker       { def m: Mii       }

trait Priority2 {
  implicit def f2mxy[A, B](f: Function1[A, B]) = 
    new MxyMaker[A, B] { def m = new Mxy[A, B] { def apply(a: A) = f(a) } }
}
// Bunch of missing priorities here in the full case
object Convert extends Priority2 {
  implicit def f2mii[A](f: Function1[A, Int])(implicit evA: Int =:= A) = 
    new MiiMaker { def m = new Mii{ 
        def apply(i: Int) = (f.asInstanceOf[Function1[Int,Int]]).apply(i) 
    } }
}
```

Now whenever you have an `Int => Int` you get a `Mii`, and for anything else you get a `Mxy`.  (If you don't ask for `evA` then `((a: Any) => 5).m` comes up as a `Mii` because of the contravariance of Function1 in its input argument parameter.)

So far so good.  But what if you are in a context where you need not a `Mii` but a `Mxy`?

```
def muse[A, B](m: Mxy[A,B]) = ???
```

Now inferring the most specific type *isn't* what you want.  But, alas,

```
scala> muse( ((i: Int) => 5).m )
  <console>:18: error: type mismatch;
   found   : Mii
   required: Mxy[?,?]
                muse( ((i: Int) => 5).m )
                                      ^
```

Now what?  If `Mxy` were a superclass of `Mii` it would be fine, but it's not and I can't change it.  I could parameterize `m` with an output type and have a set of typeclass-like things that do the correct conversion depending on output type *and* then ask the user to type `.m[Mxy]` manually.  But I want to skip the manual part and somehow pick up the type context from the call to `muse` without messing up things like `val mippy = ((i: Int) = 5).m`.

<sup>The astute may be able to think of a case like this in the wild, but it's easier to work with this "minimization" to get the principles right.</sup>

Comment: How about muse requiring a MxyMaker?: `def muse[A, B](m: MxyMaker[A,B]) = { m.m }` Or if you don't want to change `muse` then wrapping it with an outer method: `def museOuter[A, B](m: MxyMaker[A, B]) = { muse(m.m) }`

Comment: @AkosKrivachy - Unfortunately, I can't change `muse`, nor does the _actual_ case I care about admit wrapping with outer methods (because there are far too many methods like `muse`).

Comment: Given that you cannot have `Mxy` be a superclass `Mii`, why not simply define an implicit conversion from `Mii` to `Mxy[Int,Int]`?

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles - Because in general you don't want them jumping around without knowing about it, as Mii is unboxed while Mxy is boxed and the only reason to use Mii normally is for performance.  Otherwise it's what I'd do, though--good idea in general.